# Should data normalization be applied to the y labels or only to the x data, and why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalization

I saw places saying that when using a NN you should **SOMETIMES** normalize your data: we take the `X_train`, subtract the mean and divide by the std.

Is the following statements correct, and if so, why?

- We only normalize the `X` data, and the `y` data stays as is.

***Note***: I am asking the same question I did earlier today, since my original post was closed and there is no dialogue or a way to reopen my question. The [similar Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409000/should-we-normalize-target-data-as-well-as-input-data) associated with my post does not answer my question, it talks about why we normalize `X`, but not about the normalization of `y` and the reasons for it.

Comment: Please don’t ask same question twice. Instead edit your initial question to add more details. It was closed as a duplicate of another question that seems to answer it, so please add details on what exactly is not clear for you about it.

Comment: @Tim I did add more information. There is no option to call a moderator or something; someone decided for me that the answer given answers my question, without asking me. I remember there is an option to ask the OP if the other post answers their question, but it wasn't used here. The best thing I could think of is opening a new issue